# Displaying New Products in Home Page

Tags: extensions, new-products, home-page

I am using [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/top-seller-new-feature-most-viewed-catalog-sale-recently-ordered-all-products-7-in-one-catalog-by-etatvasoft.html) extension to display New Products in Home Page. I disabled the extension from Admin Panel but it is still displaying New Products in Home Page. Cache is disabled in my site. Why it is doing so ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable extension, you can disbale it from module xml.

Open your module xml file from `app/etc/modules`

You can see code like this

`<active>true</active>` replce it with `<active>false</active>`